# C# EXT: GridCommand: single click expands double click collapses RowExpander

Tags: c#, extjs

I have a grid command "Edit" which expands a RowExpander with single click but you need to double click it to collapse it.
Is it possible to collapse it with single click?

```
<ext:CommandColumn runat="server" Width="70">
       <Commands>
            <ext:GridCommand Icon="NoteEdit" CommandName="Edit">
                   <ToolTip Text="Edit" />
            </ext:GridCommand>
       </Commands>
       <Listeners>
            <Command Handler="if (command=='Edit') 
                   #{RowExpanderFormFields}.expandRow(recordIndex);" />
       </Listeners>
</ext:CommandColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added js check if rowexpander is expanded and if yes then collapse it.

```
<Command Handler="if (command=='Edit') 
{
         if(#{RowExpanderFormFields}.isExpanded(recordIndex))
                 #{RowExpanderFormFields}.collapseRow(recordIndex);
         else
                 #{RowExpanderFormFields}.expandRow(recordIndex);
}
```